# Error building gcc 4.8.3 from source: libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I 'm using gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010 for the compile but I have also tried gcc 4.1.2 and I get the same error.

for gcc 5.2.1

strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6|grep CXXABI gives

```
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.2 
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_1.3.8
CXXABI_1.3.9
CXXABI_TM_1
CXXABI_FLOAT128
```

For the compiler being compiled gcc 4.8.3

```
strings gcc-build/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6|grep CXXABI

CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1 
CXXABI_1.3.2 
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_TM_1
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_TM_1
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_1.3.3
```

i.e no 1.3.8

prior to running configure and make I also tried:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
../gcc-4.8.3/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu
make
```

Error message:

```
msgfmt -o fr.mo ../../../../gcc-4.8.3/libstdc++-v3/po/fr.po
msgfmt: gcc-build/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
msgfmt: Makefile:460: recipe for target 'de.mo' failed
```

When compiling with gcc 4.1.2 I get the same error:

```
msgfmt -o fr.mo ../../../../libstdc++-v3/po/fr.po
gcc-build/gcc-4.8.3/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
Makefile:460: recipe for target 'de.mo' failed
```

When compiling with gcc 4.1.2 i did the following prior to configure and make

```
#where libraries i have compiled with gcc 4.1.2 are located i.e 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/devtools/gcc-4.1.2/lib
#where libstdc++.so.6 is
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-4.1.2/lib64

strings /opt/gcc-4.1.2/lib64/libstdc++.so.6|grep CXXABI
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3
```

which makes me wonder where CXXABI_1.3.8 is coming from. I also did a 'make distclean' between changing compiler

Comment: So you have a library or some such that is requiring a newer version of the C++ library than the compiler you are linking with will support. Recompile the whole project with the older compiler, should solve it.

Comment: Some header-file (or object file) you are using will have a requirement for a newer C++ library. I'm not sure what further information you require to fix this problem, but basically, you will have to fix your build environment so that it has the relevant C++ library...  You may be able to rebuild `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55` with a different compiler, perhaps?

Comment: Note that the C++ library that comes with a particular compiler version will support a particular C++ ABI version, so mixing usage of compilers will give this kind of error.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Building libicuuc.so.55 with gcc 4.1.2 and then building gcc solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, this problem occurs when a library that has been built with a newer compiler is linked with an older version of C++ library - or sometimes when a newer headerfile is used to compile something that then links to an older C++ library.

It is also possible come up with a similar problem when moving binary files from one system to another, if the shared libraries installed on the "new system" are older than the ones on which the code was built.

There are typically three plausible solutions:
 1. Recompile the offending library with an older compiler.
 2. Install a newever version of the C++ library.
 3. Rebuild the C++ library from sources (with a new enough compiler).

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled upon the same problem with a bit newer compiler combination, i.e. using gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609 while building GCC 4.8.5. The solution worked out so far apparently did the job and gives valuable general explanation of the problem. I offer further details and an alternative solution below.

The error message in question comes from the `msgfmt` program - part of gettext, an internationalization and localization system:

```
$ which msgfmt
/usr/bin/msgfmt
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/msgfmt
gettext: /usr/bin/msgfmt
```

`msgfmt` gets called by the GCC build system to compile messages emited by the C++ standard library (libstdc++) that is currently being built. `msgfmt` is a dynamically linked executable, linked (among others) against `libicuuc.so.55` - a cross-platform Unicode based globalization library:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/msgfmt
    libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007ff133f47000)
```

(other dependencies not shown for clarity)

The icuuc library is a dynamically linked shared object itself that depends on the stdc++ library:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff688a16000)
```

(other dependencies not shown for clarity)

The above listing was generated using my interactive shell environment, which resolves the dependency on `libstdc++.so.6` to the system-wide version of the C++ library located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. However, the GCC build environment apparently resolves this dependency to the C++ library generated on the earlier stage of the current build process, i.e. to the one located in `$TOP_BUILD_DIR/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs` - recall the originally posted error message:

```
msgfmt: gcc-build/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
```

I get a fairly similar output:

```
msgfmt: /opt/build/gcc/gcc-4.8.4/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
```

Now, answering the original question, the string 'CXXABI_1.3.8' comes from the `libicuuc.so.55` library, which requires that the `libstdc++.so.6` library it depends upon, provides a particular ABI version:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 | grep CXXABI
CXXABI_1.3.8
CXXABI_1.3
```

To summarize, the GCC build system creates a circular dependency, which mixes system-wide binaries with local libraries:

```
libstdc++ (currenlty built) > msgfmt > libicuuc.so.55 > libstdc++.so.6
```

by resolving `libstdc++.so.6` to it's own library structure instead of the system-wide version.

The solution proposed by [Mats Petersson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919155/mats-petersson), which involves rebuilding the `libicuuc.so.55` library such that it depends on an older version of `libstdc++.so.6`, which is (hopefully) compatible with the GCC build system, is certainly valid. However, it seems a bit unnatural for my taste, as it requires playing around with dependencies of a system-wide binary, which is out of control of any non-root user.

My alternative solution involves building the custom version of the gettext package instead, such that the `msgfmt` binary is self-contained and its dependencies do not interfere with the GCC build system. It can be achieved by installing the custom version of gettext in `/opt` and adjusting the relevant paths using environment modules.

Comment: How can you configure GCC to use a custom `msgfmt` by adjusting env. modules?

Comment: @camilo I'm talking [environment modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) that help you dynamically modify your env. I suggest to create a module file that adjusts the env ($PATH, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and $MANPATH) for a custom installation of `gettext` and then insert that module in a shell used to build GCC. When the time comes the build system will call your custom version of `msgfmt`, which you providently compiled e.g. as a static binary, thus lifting the problem of incompatible libstdc++ ABIs.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when I tried to build GCC 4.8.5 from source on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with GCC 5.4.0.

As a workaround I just dropped LD_LIBRARY_PATH only for msgfmt command in makefiles. To be precise I give the exact commands I executed to get the build successful:

1 - extract the sources

```
tar zxfv gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz 
cd gcc-4.8.5
```

2 - modify call of msgfmt (add LD_LIBRARY_PATH= ) and make sure it is correct

```
vi ./libstdc++-v3/po/Makefile.in
vi ./libstdc++-v3/po/Makefile.am
grep "MSGFMT =" ./libstdc++-v3/po/Makefile.in ./libstdc++-v3/po/Makefile.am
./libstdc++-v3/po/Makefile.in:MSGFMT = LD_LIBRARY_PATH= msgfmt
./libstdc++-v3/po/Makefile.am:MSGFMT = LD_LIBRARY_PATH= msgfmt
```

3 - configure (I restriced multilib to 64bit only, because I don't have libc6-dev-i386 installed on my 64bit host and don't want to do it only for this build), build and install

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.8.5 --with-multilib-list=m64
make
make install
```

Comment: This must be the right answer

Comment: So, what were those lines set to before your change?

Answer (score 0):

just copy `libstdc++.so` in system installed directory to your gcc source appropriate directory, remember to rename it properly.

attention: you may need to copy several times as during compiling, gcc will replace that library several times.

Comment: Seems to be working... let's see whether the build concludes.