# Getting ImportError /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.11' not found

Tags: python, linux, libstdc++, rdkit

I'm currently trying to run a Python program that uses RDKit and am facing an error. The get straight to the point, the complete traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from train import Trainer
  File "/home/user1/repo1/train.py", line 12, in <module>
    from utils import make_batches
  File "/home/user1/repo1/utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rdkit import Chem, DataStructs
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/user1conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdkit/Chem/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from rdkit import DataStructs
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/user1conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdkit/DataStructs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from rdkit.DataStructs import cDataStructs
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by /home/user1/anaconda3/envs/user1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rdkit/DataStructs/../../../../libRDKitDataStructs.so.1)
```

I've taken a look at [this Git Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5017) and tried all the suggestions there, but none of them have worked. I also took a look at the following Stack Overflow questions as well: [uwsgi: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235647/uwsgi-usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found-required-by-u) and [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found) but the answers have not been able to solve my problem either.

For a bit more information:

1. OS: Ubuntu 16.04
2. Python version: 3.7.5
3. Output of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is currently nothing (I've tried to set this to what the answers have suggested).
4. I'm currently using a Conda environment and also downloaded RDKit from Anaconda.

Would anyone know what the potential problem may be? I'm a bit perplexed as nothing seems to be working and I don't know where to start diagnosing the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you download the RDKit?

Comment: By running the command `conda install -c conda-forge rdkit` as explained in the ["Installation" section in the documentation](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html#conda-forge-package).

Comment: And this program is executing that version of python?

Answer (score 1):

(This has been answered hundreds of times on StackOverflow)

This means the `libRDKitDataStructs.so.1` library was built by a new version of GCC and your system compiler is an older version. The library depends on the version of `libstdc++.so` that comes with the new version, but it's finding the old one from your system compiler.

You need to ensure that the runtime linker knows how to find the new `libstdc++.so`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths an https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic

Answer (score 0):

For all those stuck with a similar problem, update your Anaconda/Miniconda with the following command:

```
conda deactivate

conda update conda
```

It works for me, hope it can help someone.