# How to upgrade version of CXXABI in libstdc++.so.6

Tags: libstdc++

This is connected to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587320/getting-importerror-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1). I've done a bit of research and managed to do the following:

I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to `/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/` since this is where my `libstdc++.so.6` is located. After that I kept getting the "could not find `CXXABI_1.3.11` which is required version" error, and so did:

```
strings /home/user1/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI
```

which outputs:

```
CXXABI_1.3
CXXABI_1.3.1
CXXABI_1.3.2
CXXABI_1.3.3
CXXABI_1.3.4
CXXABI_1.3.5
CXXABI_1.3.6
CXXABI_1.3.7
CXXABI_1.3.8
CXXABI_1.3.9
CXXABI_TM_1
CXXABI_FLOAT128
```

I'm assuming that in order for the original program to run properly, I need to be seeing `CXXABI_1.3.11` when I run the `strings` command as I did.

Does anybody know how I might be able to upgrade the version here? Thanks.

Comment: It's still the same problem as in your other question: you need to ensure the right version of `libstdc++.so` is found at runtime. Clearly the one in `/home/user1/anaconda3/lib` is not the right one. You can't "upgrade the version of CXXABI in libstdc++.so.6", you need to use a different libstdc++.so instead.

Comment: Voting to close as a dup of your other one: [Getting ImportError /usr/lib/x86\_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI\_1.3.11' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587320/getting-importerror-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxxabi-1)